# Spring Security Login isn't navigating after authentication

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc, spring-security

I need some help.
Can you tell me what is wrong in my Spring Security project. 
here is my **web.xml:**

```
      <display-name>Spring Project</display-name>

        <welcome-file-list>
                <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>


        <context-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <context-param>
                <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
                <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
        </context-param>


        <listener>
                <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                        <param-value></param-value>
                </init-param>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <filter>
                <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
                <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Spring security filters -->

    <filter>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
                <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**security-config.xml**

```
 <security:http auto-config="true">
           <security:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.xhtml" default-target-url="/succes.xhtml"  />
           <security:logout logout-url="/app/logout" logout-success-url="/app/main" />
    </security:http>


      <security:authentication-manager>
                <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
                        <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />
                </security:authentication-provider>
      </security:authentication-manager>


     <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
                <property name="hideUserNotFoundExceptions" value="false" />
     </bean>

      <bean id="authenticationManager"   class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
                <constructor-arg>
                        <ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
                </constructor-arg>
     </bean>

</beans>
```

**Here is my login page.**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="/WEB-INF/templates/general.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="title"><h:outputText value="Please Sign In" /></ui:define>
        <ui:define name="header"><h:outputText value="Please Sign In" /></ui:define>


         <ui:define name="content">
             <h:form id="loginForm" prependId="false">
                     <p:fieldset styleClass="fieldset" legend="Authentication Form">
                             <p:focus />
                             <p:messages id="messages" />

                             <h:panelGrid id="logPanelGrid" style="margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 25px; text-align: right" cellspacing="8" columns="3">
                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                                <h:outputText value="User Name:" />
                                                <h:outputText style="color:red" value="*  " />
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                        <p:inputText id="userName" value="#{userManagedBean.userName}" required="true" label="User Name" title="Enter your User Name!" />
                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                                <p:message id="userNameMsg" for="userName" />
                                                <p:tooltip for="userName" styleClass="tooltip" showEvent="focus" hideEvent="blur" />
                                        </h:panelGroup>

                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                                <h:outputText value="Enter Password:" />
                                                <h:outputText style="color:red" value="*  " />
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                        <p:password id="pass" value="#{userManagedBean.password}" required="true" label="Password" title="Please enter a password!" />
                                        <h:panelGroup>
                                                <p:message id="passMsg" for="pass" />
                                                <p:tooltip for="pass" styleClass="tooltip" showEvent="focus" hideEvent="blur" />
                                        </h:panelGroup>



                                     <p:commandButton id="submitButton"  update="logPanelGrid,messages" action="#{userManagedBean.doLogin()}"  value="SignIn" />

                             </h:panelGrid>
                     </p:fieldset>
             </h:form>
        </ui:define> 

 </ui:composition>
```

**For implements authentication i create UserManagedbean with doLogin() method.**

```
 package com.app.managed;

    import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
    import javax.inject.Inject;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    import com.app.model.UserEntity;
    import com.app.service.UserService;

    @Component
    @ViewScoped
    public class UserManagedBean {

     public UserManagedBean(){
         System.out.println("Just for test, usermanagedbean nstantiated");
     }
     @Inject
     private UserService userService;

     @Inject 
     private UserAuthenticationProviderServiceImpl userAuth;

     private UserEntity user;

     String userName;
     String password;


    public UserEntity getUser() {
         return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserEntity user) {
         this.user = user;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean doLogin() {
        UserEntity user = userService.loadUserEntityByUsername(userName);
        return userAuth.processUserAuthentication(user);
    }



    }
```

**also i create UserAuthenticationProviderService**

```
package com.app.managed;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.app.model.UserEntity;


/**
 * Provides processing service to set user authentication session
 * 
 * @author Arthur Vin
 */
@Service("userAuthenticationProviderServiceImpl")
public class UserAuthenticationProviderServiceImpl implements UserAuthenticationProviderService {

        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        /**
         * Process user authentication
         * 
         * @param user
         * @return
         */
        public boolean processUserAuthentication(UserEntity user) {

                try {
                        System.out.println("11111");
                        Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword());
                        System.out.println("user.getUserName(), user.getPassword()" + user.getUserName() + " " + user.getPassword() );

                    Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);

                    return true;
            } catch(AuthenticationException e) {
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
                                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage(), "Sorry!"));

                    return false;
            }
    }

    public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() {
            return authenticationManager;
    }

    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
            this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

}
```

**AND Implements UserDeatailsService**

```
  package com.app.service;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;

    import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
    import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
    import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;

    import org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputText;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
    import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import com.app.dao.UserDao;
    import com.app.model.UserEntity;
    import com.app.service.intf.UserServiceIntf;


    /**
     * Service providing service methods to work with user data and entity.
     * 
     * @author Arthur Vin
     */
    @Service("userService")
    public class UserService implements UserServiceIntf, UserDetailsService {
            @Autowired
            private UserDao userDao;

        /**
         * Check user name availability. UI ajax use.
         * 
         * @param ajax event
         * @return
         */
        public boolean checkAvailable(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {

                InputText inputText = (InputText) event.getSource();
                String value = (String) inputText.getValue();

                boolean available = userDao.checkAvailable(value);

                if (!available) {
                        FacesMessage message = constructErrorMessage(null, String.format(getMessageBundle().getString("userExistsMsg"), value));
                        getFacesContext().addMessage(event.getComponent().getClientId(), message);
                } else {
                        FacesMessage message = constructInfoMessage(null, String.format(getMessageBundle().getString("userAvailableMsg"), value));
                        getFacesContext().addMessage(event.getComponent().getClientId(), message);
                }

                return available;
        }

        /**
         * Construct UserDetails instance required by spring security
         */
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

                UserEntity user = userDao.loadUserByUserName(userName);

                if (user == null) {
                    System.out.println("NUL11!!");
                        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(getMessageBundle().getString("badCredentials"), userName));

                }

                Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
                System.out.println("user.getUserName()"+ user.getUserName());
                User userDetails = new User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(), authorities);

                return userDetails;
        }

        /**
         * Retrieves full User record from database by user name
         * 
         * @param userName
         * @return UserEntity
         */
        public UserEntity loadUserEntityByUsername(String userName) {
                return userDao.loadUserByUserName(userName);
        }

        protected FacesMessage constructErrorMessage(String message, String detail){
                return new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, message, detail);
        }

        protected FacesMessage constructInfoMessage(String message, String detail) {
                return new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, message, detail);
        }

        protected FacesMessage constructFatalMessage(String message, String detail) {
                return new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, message, detail);
        }

        protected FacesContext getFacesContext() {
                return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        }

        protected ResourceBundle getMessageBundle() {
                return ResourceBundle.getBundle("message-labels");
        }

        public UserDao getUserDao() {
                return userDao;
        }

        public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
                this.userDao = userDao;
        }

    }
```

also i have UserEntity class with username password columns.
  So then i click in my login.xhtml page on SignIn button , with right userName and password page reloads and nothing else.
   Can someone tell me,what i did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `doLogin()` method breaks the contract for the action attribute on your `p:commandButton`:

```
public boolean doLogin() {
        UserEntity user = userService.loadUserEntityByUsername(userName);
        return userAuth.processUserAuthentication(user);
    }
```

This method returns a `boolean`. If you want to navigate elsewhere, it should return a `String`:

```
 public String doLogin() {
        UserEntity user = userService.loadUserEntityByUsername(userName);
        boolean result = userAuth.processUserAuthentication(user);

        if (result) {
            return "path/To/Landing/Page";
        }

          //result was false - handle login error condition

          //keep the view scope bean alive and don't change the page
          return null;
    }
```

After the `action` method fires, the `String` that is returned is the path to the view that the user should be taken to afterwards. In your case, I suspect that this will be different based on the outcome of the authentication, but currently, you don't have one.

Due to your method signiture, irrespective of any Spring Security stuff, you're ending up where you started.

Comment: maybe you help me, i want then i click on submit button if authentication return true , show message box, in my template i create div block.What i need to have in IF case , for show on this message?
<div id="greeting">
                                <c:if test="${not empty currentUser.name}">
                                        <b>Welcome,</b> ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName} | <a href="${request.contextPath}/app/logout"><img alt="" title="Logout" src="${request.contextPath}/resources/css/images/logout.png" /></a>
                                </c:if>
                        </div>

Comment: and i have new Error , then i try to authenticate right user, i get NullpoinerException at   UserAuthenticationProviderServiceImpl 
Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);

Comment: @MeetJoeBlack If you want to stay on the same page irrespective of if the log in was true or false, simply return null in all cases. The page will not change, and the same instance view scoped bean will stay alive. To show a dialog on true, you could use RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("yourDialogName.show()"); to conditionally, programatically display your dialog.